# Insert into a table using a stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have this simple stored procedure, where it would add a column to my `Orders` table

```
create or replace PROCEDURE ADD_ORDER 
(
  CUSTOMER_ID IN NUMBER 
, NEW_ORDER_ID OUT NUMBER 
) AS 
DECLARE
  NEW_ORDER_ID := MAX(ORDERS.ORDER_NO) + 1;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO ORDERS(ORDER_NO, REP_NO, CUST_NO, ORDER_DT, STATUS)
  VALUES( NEW_ORDER_ID, 36, CUSTOMER_ID, CURDATE(), 'C')
END ADD_ORDER;
```

It is saying the the declare part is not at the correct place (I think), and also it should not end there. Here is what it is saying at the error screen:

> Error(6,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following:
> begin function pragma procedure subtype type      current cursor delete    exists prior external language The symbol "begin was inserted before "DECLARE" to continue.
>
> Error(11,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:     , ; return returning

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong here ?

Comment: Your code has multiple errors.  In any case, you should be doing this using a sequence or identity column, not by calculating a new order id in a stored procedure.

Comment: Gordon is right. If two processes call this procedure at the same time, they try to insert rows with the same order_no. Use a sequence or identity column instead, just as Gordon suggests. As to your error: Remove the `DECLARE`. It is implicit in a stored procedure. Then, you cannot get `MAX` without selecting from the table. And `CURDATE()` is not an Oracle function. You want `SYSDATE` instead.

Comment: On a side note: You should stick to the names chosen in your database. If the table has a column `CUST_NO`, then don't call it `CUSTOMER_ID` at another place. And use prefixes for your variables (e.g. `p_` for parameter or `pi_` for parameter IN or `vi_` for variable IN or whatever. Stay consistent here as well). Thus you can always tell what you are dealing with (e.g. in `SELECT * INTO v_order_row FROM orders WHERE order_no = p_order_no`).

Comment: Another error in your code is the missing semicolon after the `INSERT` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your code.

```
 NEW_ORDER_ID := MAX(ORDERS.ORDER_NO) + 1; --not be used liked it.
```

Use below code

```
create or replace PROCEDURE ADD_ORDER 
(
  CUSTOMER_ID IN NUMBER 
, NEW_ORDER_ID OUT NUMBER 
) AS 

  V_NEW_ORDER_ID NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT NVL(MAX(ORDER_NO),0)+1 INTO V_NEW_ORDER_ID FROM ORDERS;
    
    INSERT INTO ORDERS(ORDER_NO, REP_NO, CUST_NO, ORDER_DT, STATUS)
    VALUES( V_NEW_ORDER_ID, 36, CUSTOMER_ID, CURDATE(), 'C');
    
    NEW_ORDER_ID:=V_NEW_ORDER_ID;
   
    /* 
        * CURDATE() -> I am assuming it is user defined function. You can also use SYSDATE, CURRENT_DATE istead of CURDATE()
        * OUT Parameter is a write-only parameter. You cannot read value from OUT Parameter
    */
    
END ADD_ORDER;
```

Comment: I have tried using your code, but it is still saying the error "Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following: ...".

Comment: Removing DECLARE keyword from code. DECLARE is not allowed in Procedure and Function. I forgot to remove DECLARE keyword. I am sorry for this. I copied the code and after editing, I forget to remove the DECLARE from the code. @Thorsten Kettner thanks for highlighting this. In terms of copy-paste, I forget to remove DECLARE keyword.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned, it is a bad idea to select the maximum order number and then use that to insert a row. If two processes do this at the same time, they try to insert rows with the same order number.

Better use Oracle's built-in features `SEQUENCE` or `IDENTITY`.

Here is how you could create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE orders 
(
  order_no  NUMBER(8) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  rep_no    NUMBER(3)    DEFAULT 36       NOT NULL,
  cust_no   NUMBER(8)                     NOT NULL,
  order_dt  DATE         DEFAULT SYSDATE  NOT NULL,
  status    VARCHAR2(1)  DEFAULT 'C'      NOT NULL
);
```

And this is what your procedure would look like then:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_order 
(
  in_cust_no   IN  NUMBER,
  out_order_no OUT NUMBER 
) AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO ORDERS(cust_no) VALUES (in_cust_no)
    RETURNING order_no INTO out_order_no;
END add_order;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4b49723c15eb810c01077286e171bc95

Comment: I am not creating a table here, just this procedure to add into an existing table, so I don't think this is an option.

Answer (score 0):

**Few things need to be correct.**

If you're expecting to write a `PROCEDURE` or a `FUNCTION` you don't have to use the `DECLARE` keyword. In writing a test script or something, you should use the `DECLARE` keyword to declare variables.
When writing a procedure,

1. All the parameters should be inside the brackets.
2. Variables should define between `AS` and `BEGIN` keywords and should give the datatype.

If you need to fetch the MAX number of ORDERS TAB you have to write a SQL query for that. Because the `MAX` function only can be used inside a `SQL`. Additionally, if you interest there is an in-built feature call `SEQUENCE` in ORACLE which can use for `NEW_ORDER_ID`. You can check with the link below.
[adding a sequence for oracle plsql](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php)

I did some changes to your code. Hope it's working fine now. Please take a visit here.

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_ORDER (
    CUSTOMER_ID     IN NUMBER 
    NEW_ORDER_ID    OUT NUMBER
) AS

  CURSOR get_max_order_no IS
    SELECT MAX(order_no)
    FROM ORDERS;
  rec_ NUMBER := 0;  

BEGIN

  OPEN get_max_order_no;
  FETCH get_max_order_no INTO rec_;
  CLOSE get_max_order_no;

  NEW_ORDER_ID := rec_ + 1;

  INSERT INTO ORDERS
    (ORDER_NO, REP_NO, CUST_NO, ORDER_DT, STATUS)
  VALUES 
    (NEW_ORDER_ID, 36, CUSTOMER_ID, SYSDATE, 'C');

END ADD_ORDER;
```